# Change pixel color given the pixel position in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a JPEG image and I want to change the color of 3 adjacent pixels in the image, like blue for example.  Suppose the positions of these pixels are given, like `(10,10), (10,11), (10,12)`.

Any idea on how we can do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that through indexing.  Supposing your image is stored in `im`, and you have read it through [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html).  Assuming your image is in colour and is of type `uint8`, you would simply do this:

```
im(10,10:12,1) = 0;
im(10,10:12,2) = 0;
im(10,10:12,3) = 255;
```

This will change pixels at row 10, columns 10 - 12 and modify each of their colour planes so that the red channel is 0, the green channel is 0 and the blue channel is 255.  This would effectively make the pixels at these three locations blue.

However, if your image was only grayscale and a single 2D matrix, you would need to create a colour version before doing the above.  That can simply be done by replicating each image for each of the channels.  In other words:

```
im = cat(3,im,im,im);
```

You can then use `im` and colour whatever pixels you wish.

---

If you want to make this vectorized, you certainly can by using [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
im(10,10:12,:) = repmat([0 0 255], 3, 1);
```

This will achieve the same result as above.

---

In general, if you want to do this for any one row and a variable number of column locations, you would do this:

```
im(row,col1:col2,:) = repmat([c1 c2 c3], col2 - col1 + 1, 1);
```

`row` would be the row that you're looking for, `col1` and `col2` would be the beginning and ending column of what you want to change, and `[c1 c2 c3]` would be the tuple of RGB components that you want to set these locations to.  `c1` is the red component, `c2` is the green component and `c3` is the blue component respectively.  The above code will work independently of how many columns you want to set, provided that you don't go outside the image of course!